# Fatal error. Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\libraries\Table.php on line 256

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I'm getting this error when i try to execute 2 function in the same controller. the 1st one works fine, but get the error

> 'Fatal error. Cannot use object of type stdClass as array  in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\system\libraries\Table.php on line 256'.

Controller

```
<?phpif (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed'); class tables extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->database();
    //load the search model
    $this->load->model('mtables');
}

public function index() {

}

public function current_users() {

    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "tables/current_users";

    $table = 'dept_officer_view';
    $total_row = $this->mtables->record_count($table);

    $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $result_per_page = 10;
    $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;', $str_links);

    $datatable1 = $this->mtables->fetch_data($result_per_page, $this->uri->segment(3), $table);
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('dept_officer_table_view', array(
        'datatable1' => $datatable1,
        'result_per_page' => $result_per_page
    ));
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

public function crpo_users() {

    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "tables/crpo_users";

    $table = 'crpo_view';
    $total_row = $this->mtables->record_count($table);

    $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $result_per_page = 10;

    $datatable2 = $this->mtables->fetch_data($result_per_page, $this->uri->segment(3), $table);


    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('crpo_table_view', array(
        'datatable2' => $datatable2,
        'result_per_page' => $result_per_page));
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
) 
?>
```

Model

```
<?php
class mtables extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

// Count all record of table "contact_info" in database.
public function record_count($table) {
    return $this->db->count_all("$table");
}

// Fetch data according to per_page limit.
public function fetch_data($limit,$start,$table) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start*$limit);
    $query = $this->db->get("$table");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
}?>
```

View 1
crpo_table_view.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header"> Users</h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li>View Users</li>
                <li class="active">Child Rights Promoting Officer</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-offset-1">
            <a href="<?= base_url('users') ?>" class="btn btn-default">Department Officers</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="<?= base_url('crpo') ?>"class="btn btn-default active">Child Rights Promoting Officers</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="<?= base_url('donors') ?>"class="btn btn-default">Donors/ Foster Parents</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- pagination -->                
    <div>

        <?php
        // generate the table
        $this->table->set_heading('Fisrt name', 'Last name', 'Contact no','Username', 'Email','Official Address','DS Division','District');
        echo $this->table->generate($datatable2);

        // generate the page navigation

        echo $this->pagination->create_links();
        ?>

    </div>



</div>
</div>
```

View 2
donor_table_view.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header"> Users</h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li>View Users</li>
                <li class="active">Donors/Foster Parents</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-offset-1">
            <a href="<?= base_url('users') ?>" class="btn btn-default">Department Officers</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="<?= base_url('crpo') ?>"class="btn btn-default">Child Rights Promoting Officers</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <a href="<?= base_url('donors') ?>"class="btn btn-default active">Donors/ Foster Parents</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- pagination -->                
    <div>

        <?php
        // generate the table
        $this->table->set_heading('Fisrt name', 'Last name', 'Contact no','Address','Username', 'Email');
        echo $this->table->generate($datatable3);

        // generate the page navigation

        echo $this->pagination->create_links();
        ?>

    </div>



</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which line of code is giving the error?

Comment: just put one file code in which you got error, remove all other files, also state the line where you got error through some comment or marker

Comment: getting the error in a system file, C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter\system\libraries\Table.php on line 256
`protected function _prep_args($args)
 {
  // If there is no $args[0], skip this and treat as an associative array
  // This can happen if there is only a single key, for example this is passed to table->generate
  // array(array('foo'=>'bar'))
  if (isset($args[0]) && count($args) === 1 && is_array($args[0]) && ! isset($args[0]['data']))
  {
   $args = $args[0];
  }

  foreach ($args as $key => $val)
  {
   is_array($val) OR $args[$key] = array('data' => $val);
  }

  return $args;
 }`

Comment: line 196 in that @Kenney

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is in:

```
function _prep_args($args) {
  // If there is no $args[0], skip this and treat as an associative array
  // This can happen if there is only a single key, for example this is passed to table->generate 
  // array(array('foo'=>'bar'))
  if (isset($args[0]) && count($args) === 1 && is_array($args[0]) && ! isset($args[0]['data'])) {
    $args = $args[0];
  }
  foreach ($args as $key => $val) {
    is_array($val) OR $args[$key] = array('data' => $val);
  }
  return $args;
}
```

If `$args` is not an array, but an `stdClass`, then that would explain the error you get. To find out where it's called from with the wrong argument, you could either add

```
if ( is_object( $args ) ) throw new Exception("Bug!");
```

or

```
if ( is_object( $args ) ) { echo "<pre>"; debug_print_backtrace(); echo "</pre>"; }
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you find where in your code you call it? If you are extending `CI_Table`, you could override the `protected function _prep_args($args)` to support a `stdClass`, otherwise maybe a `(array)` cast is sufficient. Or maybe it's as simple as a typo?

Comment: I couldn't find the error, but works fine when the table library isn't used to generate the table @kenney

Comment: Ah, that's one way to circumvent the issue ;-) Well, if you tried one of the two suggestions in my answer and you got a stack trace, perhaps you could add it to your question so we can figure out where it's going wrong -  if you're interested.  Could it be on a line like `echo $this->table->generate($datatable3);`?

Comment: the result of the query must be in the format of result_array(), not  result() @Kenney

Answer (score -1):

This will do it:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
while( $res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     $res['row_name'];
};
```

Comment: Please give some explanation of your answer